# What are optimisations enabled by -Og level in G++?

Tags: g++, g++-5

Official GCC documentation doesn't give a list of optimisations enabled for C++ at the `-Og` level stating only that selected options would not harm debuggability.

I need to know the list of optimisations, do perform a *binary search* which particular one cause a bug in the inlined template class constructor call on the **ARM Cortex-M7** (arm-none-eabi) platform. I'd like to disable only the one that prevents our code from working correctly. Is there a list somewhere or an option to ask GCC itself?

Plus that would help to me check if I really see the bug in the compiler, or there is other problem revealed by the optimisations applied in that place. In the former case I need to nail it by minimal working example, and that's not the easy case. The code with `-O0` works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always see what an optimization level enables by doing: `g++ -c -Q -Og --help=optimizers | grep enabled`. From the man page:

> If the `-Q` option appears on the command line before the `--help=`
>   option, then the descriptive text displayed by `--help=` is changed.
>   Instead of describing the displayed options, an indication is given as
>   to whether the option is enabled, disabled or set to a specific value
>   (assuming that the compiler knows this at the point where the
>   `--help=` option is used).

This outputs on GCC 6.1.1 x86_64:

```
  -faggressive-loop-optimizations   [enabled]
  -fasynchronous-unwind-tables      [enabled]
  -fauto-inc-dec                    [enabled]
  -fcombine-stack-adjustments       [enabled]
  -fcompare-elim                    [enabled]
  -fcprop-registers                 [enabled]
  -fdce                             [enabled]
  -fdefer-pop                       [enabled]
  -fdelete-null-pointer-checks      [enabled]
  -fdse                             [enabled]
  -fearly-inlining                  [enabled]
  -fforward-propagate               [enabled]
  -ffunction-cse                    [enabled]
  -fgcse-lm                         [enabled]
  -fguess-branch-probability        [enabled]
  -finline                          [enabled]
  -finline-atomics                  [enabled]
  -fipa-profile                     [enabled]
  -fipa-pure-const                  [enabled]
  -fipa-reference                   [enabled]
  -fira-hoist-pressure              [enabled]
  -fira-share-save-slots            [enabled]
  -fira-share-spill-slots           [enabled]
  -fivopts                          [enabled]
  -fjump-tables                     [enabled]
  -flifetime-dse                    [enabled]
  -fmath-errno                      [enabled]
  -fpeephole                        [enabled]
  -fplt                             [enabled]
  -fprefetch-loop-arrays            [enabled]
  -frename-registers                [enabled]
  -freorder-blocks                  [enabled]
  -frtti                            [enabled]
  -fsched-critical-path-heuristic   [enabled]
  -fsched-dep-count-heuristic       [enabled]
  -fsched-group-heuristic           [enabled]
  -fsched-interblock                [enabled]
  -fsched-last-insn-heuristic       [enabled]
  -fsched-rank-heuristic            [enabled]
  -fsched-spec                      [enabled]
  -fsched-spec-insn-heuristic       [enabled]
  -fsched-stalled-insns-dep         [enabled]
  -fschedule-fusion                 [enabled]
  -fshort-enums                     [enabled]
  -fshrink-wrap                     [enabled]
  -fsigned-zeros                    [enabled]
  -fsplit-ivs-in-unroller           [enabled]
  -fsplit-wide-types                [enabled]
  -fssa-backprop                    [enabled]
  -fstdarg-opt                      [enabled]
  -fstrict-volatile-bitfields       [enabled]
  -fno-threadsafe-statics           [enabled]
  -ftrapping-math                   [enabled]
  -ftree-builtin-call-dce           [enabled]
  -ftree-ccp                        [enabled]
  -ftree-ch                         [enabled]
  -ftree-coalesce-vars              [enabled]
  -ftree-copy-prop                  [enabled]
  -ftree-cselim                     [enabled]
  -ftree-dce                        [enabled]
  -ftree-dominator-opts             [enabled]
  -ftree-dse                        [enabled]
  -ftree-forwprop                   [enabled]
  -ftree-fre                        [enabled]
  -ftree-loop-if-convert            [enabled]
  -ftree-loop-im                    [enabled]
  -ftree-loop-ivcanon               [enabled]
  -ftree-loop-optimize              [enabled]
  -ftree-phiprop                    [enabled]
  -ftree-reassoc                    [enabled]
  -ftree-scev-cprop                 [enabled]
  -ftree-sink                       [enabled]
  -ftree-slsr                       [enabled]
  -ftree-ter                        [enabled]
  -fvar-tracking                    [enabled]
  -fvar-tracking-assignments        [enabled]
  -fweb                             [enabled]
```

Comment: Works like a charm in GCC 5.4.1. Thank you very much.